# This page has redirect loop in asp.net error

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net and was trying to make a page for my project but when ever I am running this page the error comes this page has direct loop.Please provide me any solution.

This is My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using idw.DBhelper;
using System.Web.Security;


namespace idw.realitycheck
{
      public partial class SignIn : System.Web.UI.UserControl
  {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {


      }
    public void LoginButton_onclick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        idwUser accountSystem = new idwUser();
        string userId = accountSystem.Login(email.Text,password.Text);

        if ((userId != null) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            // Use security system to set the UserID within a client-side Cookie
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userId, RememberCheckbox.Checked);
            // Redirect browser back to originating page
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userId, false);
        }
        else
        {
            Message.Text = "Login Failed!";
        }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need some additional parameter configured in `forms` element in web.config. Try `<forms name="name" loginUrl="URL" defaultUrl="URL" protection="All"/>` where `defaultUrl` is the one which  will be used by `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` if `ReturnUrl` is not present in login page querystring. Please note that you can not set `loginUrl` and `defaultUrl` both pointing to `login.aspx` and that can cause redirect loop.